# How to add OpenCV as precompiled library in Poetry?

Tags: python, opencv, virtualenv, python-poetry

I am trying to add OpenCV to my virtual environment with Poetry. OpenCV is already installed globally and can be used globally in python, but not in a virtual environment created by Poetry.

I added the library to poetry like this:

```py
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
cv2 = { path = "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/python-3.8/cv2.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so" }
```

When trying to install it with `poetry install` I get the following error message:

```
  ReadError

  file could not be opened successfully

  at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/tarfile.py:1608 in open
      1604│                 except (ReadError, CompressionError):
      1605│                     if fileobj is not None:
      1606│                         fileobj.seek(saved_pos)
      1607│                     continue
    → 1608│             raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
      1609│
      1610│         elif ":" in mode:
      1611│             filemode, comptype = mode.split(":", 1)
      1612│             filemode = filemode or "r"
```

How can I add globally installed precompiled libararies to my poetry environment?

Answer (score 4):

Running `poetry add opencv-python` in your CLI while you're in the project directory should accomplish your end goal. To use `cv2`, include `import cv2` in your Python code.

It seems that your question, however, pertains specifically to depending on a local installation using the `path` property described in [Poetry's documentation for dependency specification](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/). I believe your approach should work if you're pointing to a tarball or zip file, but that's not the case for the file you mention (pip needs other files besides the one you gave).

Why not try pointing to the tar/gzip file (e.g., 'opencv-python-4.5.5.64.tar.gz') available through [their Downloads page on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#files) instead?

EDIT: If you're using a containerizer like Docker, or Jupyter notebooks or some other GUI that already has the ability to display images built-in, you may wish to use the lighter-weight implementation, `opencv-python-headless`.

Answer (score 0):

remove the line cv2 in the pyproject.toml.
in poetry we use 'poetry add packagename' command to add a package in a virtual environement
for example, poetry add django-restframework.
make sure that your terminal is open in the same folder that the pyproject.toml file.

Comment: This doesn’t answer my question. OpenCV is already installed globally on this device and therefore I just need to add the precompiled library to the virtual environment.

Comment: okay! a virtual environment is a folder that contains a python compiler and its dependencies so try this, find the folder of your virtual  environment and go to lib\sites-packages, copy the folder containing precompiled open cv, and run your program, you can also try to add at the same time the opencv dependency [tool.poetry.dependencies] although I do not think it is necessary